# Best ways to make unique field / table column in many to many relations Jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a "Product" and "Tag' class `ManyToMany` relationship. I get Products and tags from an rss feed. Some tag names are duplicated with new product entries (while inserting them) as many products come with same tag names.

I want to make Tag names UNIQUE. If, while adding a product, a Tag already exists, the product should be added there in that tag (or I should say associated with that tag) rather a new duplicate named tag be created.

If Tag does not exists, new tag created and product added there.

**If, for example, product feed has [product 1, tag [tag1,tag2,tag3]]  ,            [product  2, tag [tag7,tag5, tag1]]**

**If product 1 is added, tag 1, tag2, tag3 are created. then for product 2, tag 1 should not be created again**

Question: Is there a built in way in JPA or I have to do check / if else() / getTagByName() each time and see if it exist.

What are my options?
I prefer a JPA option (not hibernate or ORM specific)

```
    @Entity
    public class Product {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        @ManyToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
        private List<Tag> tagList;
    //getters and setters
    }



    @Entity
    public class Tag {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        @ManyToMany (mappedBy = "tagList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
        private List<ListItem> listItemList;
        @ManyToMany (mappedBy = "tagList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
        private List<Product> productList;
    //getters and setters
    }
```

Comment: When creating a JPA entity, your data is not yet in the DB, and you JPA didn't access yet the DB (it will be done when at "persist").

I suggest you have a DAO layer (and therefore, use entities getters and setter only in theses DAOs), and you can do your checks on your DB when creating an Product or a Tag.

Comment: @clapsus so you mean, whatever field i want to maintain as UNIQUE, I should have its setter call a DAO method that first checks if it already exists. If so, do not add it again?

Comment: No, if you want a field to be unique, you cant add this annotation: @Column(unique=true), but this doesn't seem to be what you want, as this only adds the SQL UNIQUE constraint on the column, so whenever you'll try to create a new object violating that constraint, it won't be created.

Comment: And no, the setter does not call the DAO, it's the DAO that has to call the setter.

Comment: I believe you were looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513927/how-to-add-persisted-entities-in-a-relationship-marked-with-cascadetype-all Well, summing up: there is no way to do it auto-magically yet :)